# Do electrical appliances reduce the heating bill?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, energy-conservation, everyday-life, electronics

When you use an electrical appliance, most of the electricity used is turned into heat. Will the energy cost of using something like an iron be subtracted from the heating bill making it effectively free? It doesn't seem right but I would think the heating wouldn't have to 'work as hard' and as your appliance cools down the heat is eventually distributed throughout your house.

This is assuming you have electric heating.

Comment: Is your electric heating bill separate from the rest of your electricity bill? :^)

Comment: haha I don't pay for my heating Its just a curious question

Comment: A lot of discussions on the subject here.https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673836/195949

Comment: Note further that electric heating can be used with heat pumps, which can result in greater than 100% efficiency in heating your house.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They do *reduce the heating bill*, but.. Let's see some numbers.

The average power consumption of (i) a fridge is 50-100 W, (ii) a television is 50 W, (iii) a laptop is 50-100 W etc. Average power consumption of my household was in the order of 200 W which equals to about 150 kWh per month. Double those numbers and it is still nowhere near enough what an average household needs for heating. Not to mention the appliances are usually not in the same room but rather distributed around the house. While on the topic, I will just mention here that an average person outputs about 50-100 W of heat power, which you can easily verify from the average daily energy consumption of a person which is about 2000-3000 kCal (1 kCal = 4184 J and 1 W = 1 J/s).

The recommended heating power is around 60-70 W/m2 for mild climates and 70-85 W/m2 for cold climates. For a room of 20 m2 (an average-sized living room), you need from 1200 W to 1700 W of heating power. Not to mention there are other rooms in a house which also need heating.

I had a crypto miner briefly which was drawing about 1200 W, most of it converted to heat. In my living room I did not need to turn on the heating. But *it does not mean I was saving money in the end*, because my heating system was based on *gas which is in general (much) cheaper than resistive heaters (electricity) per kWh of heat*. How much is the gas cheaper than electricity? It very much depends on the country, but in my experience it ranges from 2 to 5 times. See related discussion on crypto miners and heating: [Does bitcoin miner heat as much as a heater](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/100657)

Note that (new) fancy air conditioning systems based on *heat pumps* are comparable to gas (or even better in some countries!) when it comes to operation cost, i.e. they give more heat power than they *consume* electricity. How? They take heat from the outside air no matter how cold it is - in reality, they work down to about -10 C.

To conclude - yes, the appliances are reducing the heating bill during a cold season, but not by much! And when you take into account that you have to cool down more during a summer season due to the same appliances producing unwanted heat, in best case the operation costs average out to zero throughout the year.

Comment: Side note: Your last sentence does not apply if there is no air conditionning; and the price ratio between gas heating and electrical heating also depends on the location.

Comment: @Sacha I have edited the last paragraph to be more clear. As for the gas price, you are right, and that is why I gave a range 3-5 to compare gas with the electricity price. If the ratio favors gas more than 5x it pays off to have gas generators for electricity, and if the ratio is less than 3x it might not be worth the effort to introduce the gas to your home.

Comment: This all really depends on type of house heating, gas prices vs. electricity prices and where the temperature is measured to trigger heating (usually in the living room). In my country it is currently allmost beter to heat the living room with a 2000W heater than use gas because of the insane gas prices of late.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid The price crisis will not last forever. As I said, when gas price goes beyond 2-3x ratio, most consumers will switch to electricity which will lower the demand which will as a consequence lower the gas price. I only mentioned gas heating as an example from my house. As for the temperature measurement, one sensor usually placed in every room of interest.. You will not heat a bedroom based on measurements from the living room, that would be silly :)

Comment: Related: [Does bitcoin miner heat as much as a heater](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/100657) on bitcoin.SE which expands on the details of resistive heating like a crypto miner (100% efficient if placed where you actually want the heat, rather than a basement for noise considerations), vs. heat-pump (230 to 300% efficient, in terms of room heat per kWh of electricity consumed).

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you mind if I add this post to my answer?

Comment: Feel free to copy my whole comment if you want.  If you mean just the link to the question post, you don't even need to ask.  If you mean parts of the answer I posted on that linked question, quote with attribution, please.

Comment: @MarkoGulin I live in France where the ratio is always < 2 (currently around 1.5); but I don't know if it is really an exception or if more countries have a similar ratio. If not, it's not worth editing, I let that to your appreciation.

Comment: @Sacha I checked your numbers and they seem to be valid. I am suprised to see that, in Croatia the ratio is closer to 1:4, with both electricity and natural gas being significantly cheaper than in France. I wonder why is that, especially considering France has lots of nucelar power plants. In case of France it is definitely worth installing heat pumps.

Comment: @MarkoGulin Cost of living is higher in France and energy prices have significantly increased in the last 5 years there. Due to nuclear plants, electricity has been rather competitive against gas but I don't know if it's the only reason.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Marco Gulin for his excellent answer. In facility engineering practice, the Transamerica Tower in San Francisco began turning off their lighting after hours during one of the energy cost spikes of the 1970s to save on energy costs, and they discovered that their space heating bills increased slightly in proportion. In this case (before heat pumps!) the heating load of the structure was in part supported by the heat dissipation of the overhead lighting system- in a measurable way.

I do not know what sort of lighting they were using, or whether the skyscraper was heated with gas or electricity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using an iron is effectively free in a room that would otherwise be heated by the same electricity input.

"Free" in the sense that the same heat input is being put to two purposes - heating the room and ironing the clothes - and it will cost nothing more than if the iron was off and the room was being heated by a heater to the same level.

I leverage a very similar principle for the heating of our home using a dessicant dehumidifier.

Instead of ventilating the bathroom of hot steamy air after use, and ventilating the place in general, I simply use the dehumidifier to keep the home interior dry.

This recaptures the heat in the steamy air, the drying process itself liberates heat energy from condensing the damp out of the air, and finally the dessicant process is "inefficient" in that it requires some heat input for its cycle (heat that is "wasted").

But the net effect is that I haven't had to put the central heating on this winter. Running the dehumidifier, with all windows shut and vents sealed, is enough to heat the entire premises to a comfortable level, as well as being comfortably dry as opposed to dank.

Obviously, the dehumidifier is not free to run. But it is a small fraction of the price of ordinary electric heating when windows must be open to ventilate damp, and the dehumidifier's "inefficiency" (in that it is not 100% efficient at drying air without outputting heat) is actually part of its 100% efficiency in this application, because it's purpose is not just to dry but also to heat.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you live: that is the costs of heating and the cost of electricity. E.g., in France, where 70+% of the electricity is produced by nuclear power stations and the electricity is obscenely cheap, your radiators might be just as electric as any other appliances :)

Comment: According to this website https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/electricity_prices/, France ranks **32/146** for the most expensive electricity in the world, with rank 1 being the most expensive. I cannot comment if the rank is realistic, but the price mentioned there definitely seems valid to me, i.e. I pay somewhere around that price.

Comment: @MarkoGulin meaningfully one should compare the price of electricity *in France* with the price of alternative heating method *in France*. Electric heating is certainly a reality here.

Comment: My comment was aimed to *“the electricity is obscenely cheap”*. In absolute value the electricity prices are high, I am not comparing this to the living standard in France. I would not say the electricity is made cheap, but the opposite - the gas is made more expensive to shift users towards electricity since that is what France has in abundance.